# Track C variable doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

New to Doxygen and wondering can it be used to draw a graph showing what functions use a given global variable. I have been able to get call/caller graphs working for functions and want to do something similar for a hand full of variables.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What did you try sofar?

Comment: @albert I am using version 1.8.14.

Comment: @albert I have been working on a number of files not formatted for doxygen and trying to get them prepped. I have been played with a number of the advanced tab options related graphs. I can see ones dealing with classes, functions, header files etc. I also played with node/depth restriction. I have read over the options that show documentation in eclipse, but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: Since I got a fairly rapid down vote; guess this should be evident.

Comment: I was not able to do what you want, and I was trying it for some time.

Comment: @VladP That's a pity I was hoping to use it to do some reverse engineering more so than documenting. It would have been handy a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Text wise I think there is a possibility, have a look at REFERENCED_BY_RELATION and REFERENCES_RELATION

Comment: @albert I am running doxygen now. I had seen reference by relation but it read like it was again graphing functions. Not sure how I missed reference relations use of the word 'entities'.

Comment: When reading the 2 tags in the documentation it looks a bit like the documentation is not 100% correct up to date.

Comment: Cheers; the setting got me a list of functions that use the variables. I plan to have a play with the graphviz library in the near future; I might look at graphing the reference list as a learning assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES: In a Variable description it documents all functions which have used the variable and generates a hyperlink to these functions in the code. In the function documentation, this documents all functions being used in that particular function and also generates a hyperlink to the actual code.

REFERENCES_RELATION = YES: In a function documentation, this documents all functions that have called the function being described and also generates a hyperlink tot he code.

Although this is not a graphical solution (which would be way better), this is something one can definitely work with.

Comment: Since Albert didn't move the comment to an answer, I will give you the nod.